# Boxplot no muestra la información

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter, visualización-de-datos

estoy trabajando en la visualización de datos utilizando varias boxplots en una misma figura. El df_pos tiene esta forma:

```
player  |goles|goles_p_partido|goles_p_minuto|asistencias|asist_p_partido|asist_p_minuto
Vinícius 4     0.30            0.0033         6           0.46            0.0050
Antony   2     0.28            0.0034         5           0.71            0.0086
Mbappé   6     0.75            0.0089         4           0.50            0.0059
Messi    5     0.71            0.0079         0           0.00            0.0000
...
```

Necesito mostrar 6 gráficas de cajas en una misma fila con ejes y independientes. Para hacer eso estoy utilizando este código:

```
# df_j es una fila de df_pos; para este ejemplo seran los registros de Messi
posicion=df_j['position'][0]
fig,ax=plt.subplots(ncols=6, figsize=(25,10))
df_pos=df[df['position']==posicion]
columnas=['goles','goles_p_partido','goles_p_minuto','asistencias','asist_p_partido','asist_p_minuto']
for i,col in zip(range(6),columnas):
    ax[i].boxplot(x=df_pos[[col]])
    ax[i].plot(1,df_j[col][0], marker="D", color="red")
    ax[i].tick_params(labelsize=15)
    ax[i].set_xlabel(col,fontsize=20)
```

Las gráficas de goles y asistencias las hace sin problema pero las otras 4 no muestra nada. Este es el resultado que obtengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cual es el error que tengo en el código?

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: Buen día, he probado con tu código y lo único que modifiqué fue que primero cree un `dataframe` con los datos que muestras en tu pregunta y lo llamo `df`, quité la línea de `posicion` y `df_pos` y sustituí `df_j` por `df` y funciona correctamente, [aquí](https://pastebin.com/pjxeH0BE) puedes ver la modificación que hice. En un momento redacto una forma más corta de hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Cuando creas el `boxplot` estás utilizando como referencia el `dataframe` `df_pos` que al parecer no incluye todos los datos, te recomendaría imprimir ese `dataframe` y que revises su contenido.

De igual forma, hay otra forma de conseguir lo que buscas utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.boxplot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html), de esa forma también evitas agregar los valores para los ejes "X" de las gráficas.

Utilizando un `dataframe` con los datos de tu pregunta en el archivo "sample.csv".

**Nota:** En este `dataframe` únicamente están las columnas: goles, goles_p_partido, goles_p_minuto, asistencias, asist_p_partido, asist_p_minuto.
Si en el `dataframe` original hay más entonces deberás crear una lista de columnas tal como lo estás haciendo en el código actual.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', index_col = 'player')

fig,ax=plt.subplots(ncols=6, figsize=(25,10))

jugador = 'Messi'

for i, column in enumerate(df):
    df.boxplot([column], ax=ax[i])
    ax[i].plot(1,df[column][jugador], marker="D", color="red")
```

Esto crea el siguiente conjunto de gráficas:

[image: Gráfica]